# Excel Office Add-In Office.context.auth is undefined

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, azure-active-directory, add-in

I've made an Excel Addin but I want to implement Azure AD auth. I found a great tutorial: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet

But I have a problem in the next function:

```
 function getDataWithToken(options) {
        Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(options,
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                    accessToken = result.value;
                    getData(accessToken);
                }
                else {
                    handleClientSideErrors(result);
                }
            });
    }
```

The auth-part from Office.context.auth is undefined and I have no idea where to look. You can find the whole code on the tutorial.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared I needed a newer version of office (Build 8...)